# preg_match issues when a slash is in variable

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.3

I have a dynamic list of products and I am checking agains it. issue is that in my products name if there is a / then my preg_match gives me preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier error

here is an example of product name that will work

```
$productName = "Samuel Cream Leather Sofa, Loveseat, Club Chair, & Ottoman Set";
```

and this will not work

```
$productName = "Samuel Cream Leather Sofa, Loveseat, Club Chair, w/ & Ottoman Set";



foreach ($results as $result) { 
            $decodedProduct = urldecode($product);
            if(preg_match("/$decodedProduct/",$result->nodeValue)){
            echo $decodedProduct."-------------".$result->nodeValue."<br />";
            }
}
```

Comment: If you know character which is never used in target-string, you can use it to bound your string. For example, if there's no `~` character, use it like **"~$decodedProduct~"** in preg_match() call. preg_quote() seems to be more elegant solution (suggested by ndm bellow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When inserting values into regular expressions that are not ment to act as regular expressions themselfs, then always use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote).

To avoid delimiter collisions use the second parameter of `preg_quote` to define the delimiter char that needs to be quoted too:

```
preg_match("/" . preg_quote($decodedProduct, "/") . "/", $result->nodeValue)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using stripslashes().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

```
$productName = stripslashes("Samuel Cream Leather Sofa, Loveseat, Club Chair, w/ & Ottoman Set");



foreach ($results as $result) { 
            $decodedProduct = urldecode($product);
            if(preg_match("/$decodedProduct/",$result->nodeValue)){
            echo $decodedProduct."-------------".$result->nodeValue."<br />";
            }
}
```

Comment: no I have to have the backslash in there. I cant strip it out as I search on based of that exact product name